# Regex to extract .com domains only?

Tags: regex

I've got this regex for generic domains but what would I need to alter for it to only extract .com domains?

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of difficult to guess your needs but if you want to simply match those ending in `.com` you can simply add it to the regex like this:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)\.com
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/8TuNOL/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add `.\com` to your main grouping.

Ultimatey I believe you're looking for:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+\.com)
```

This can be seen working [here](https://regex101.com/r/QJFXZm/1):

```js
const regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+\.com)/;
const sites = [
  'https://www.example.com',
  'https://www.example.org',
  'www.exampe.com',
  'www.example.org'
]

sites.forEach(function(site) {
  console.log(regex.test(site));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to know if there is a hit (dont need grouping for replace, etc.) just add

```
  (\.com)
```

to end.

you've got some overkill in there, (must have http(s) 0 or 1 times, must have www. 0 or 1 times)

but it'll do